# How to include a .dll using Qt Creator

Tags: qt, dll

I've followed the steps described in https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_link_to_a_dll
but, somehow I still get undefined reference errors.

This is what I did:

1. add to my .pro file the library folder path via INCLUDEPATH+=
2. add to my .pro file the .dll via LIBS+=
3. include the .dll (in my case "okFrontPanelDLL.h") via #include in my code

I don't know if it matters, but my library is taken from: http://intantech.com/files/RhythmStim_API_Release_170328.zip
and the extracted folder contains a single .dll and multiple source and header files (do i have to add all sources and headers from the library via SOURCES+= and HEADERS+=?).

Currently, I can declare a variable based on a class defined in the library

```
okCFrontPanel *dev;
```

but accessing functions defined for the class, e.g. calling the constructor like

```
dev = new okCFrontPanel;
```

leads to an undefined reference error.

edit: I tried direcly adding the source and header files form the library into my Sources folder instead of linking the library and the code works fine, so there is (probably) at least nothing wrong with how I am trying to use the functionalities of the library.

edit2: further information:

OS: Win 7 64 bit

Qt version: 5.9.0

compiler: MinGW 32bit

file location: /[PROJECT FOLDER]/mylibrary

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myLibrary/okFrontPanelDLL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

//    return a.exec();

    printf("hello world\n");


    okCFrontPanel *dev;
    dev = new okCFrontPanel;
//    dev->BoardModel;
    // If only one Opal Kelly board is plugged in to the host computer, we can use this.
    dev->OpenBySerial();
    // Set XEM6010 PLL to default configuration to produce 100 MHz FPGA clock.
    dev->LoadDefaultPLLConfiguration();
    // Upload RhythmStim bitfile which is compiled from RhythmStim Verilog code.
    dev->ConfigureFPGA("mylibrary/main.bit");

    printf("omg dis is working\n");
}
```

Comment: Did You run **qmake** after adding the library to Your project file?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried but it didn't help (I made sure that the .pro file is being reread by temporarily adding a non-existent .dll file to see if I get an error).

Comment: I don't know how experienced in Qt You are, so I'll ask differently. 
Did You choose build->run qmake in QtCreator with Your project as the active project and try to build after that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did (but as you have guessed correctly, I'm a Qt novice, although I have worked with it a bit a long time ago).

Comment: Next: Could You update Your post with information about:
- what Qt version are You using
- on what OS
- using what build tools (if Windows, e.g. MSVC or MinGW)
- exact code, that You wrote to add the libraries, and where are the library files located on Your PC.
Also did You try adding the library with the QtCreator wizard? (right click on the project folder in QtCreator and choosing Add Library?

Comment: I tried using the wizard but as far as I have seen it only works with .lib files.

Comment: I'm not an expert, just trying to help, because I see no one else is.
But, I wouldn't use a beta version of Qt if You want to do something with it. I mean that beta's tend to have some bugs. I think that everything You need You can find in erlier releases, like 5.8, 5.7 or the long term support version, which is 5.6. I'm using 5.7.1.
I remember having difficulties with including dll's in the past.
I do not recall how was it done in mingw. I'm using msvc2015.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good point I didn't realize (didn't expect the default installation to make me use beta). I'll test later if that is the cause!